# JDK not found(Accelarator)

Tags: java, android, appcelerator-mobile, java-6, appcelerator-studio

- jdk 32bits 1.6
- I've tested on cmd, both 'java-verion' and 'javac-version' is working fine
- I've run 'appc ti config java.home C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\bin'\
- I've run 'appc ti config JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\bin'

but still not working

Comment: Based on https://docs.axway.com/bundle/Titanium_SDK_allOS_en/page/prerequisites.html it looks like you need Java 8 (1.8) **NOT** Java 6 (1.6)

Comment: I've tried a few java versions including 1.8 and different bits but is still not working